# Deleting the same function binded with different arguments from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of functions that I add with this code using different arguments every time. It is working, it adds the same function with different parameters as arguments:

```
FunctionList.push(MyFunction.bind(null, Argument, Argument2));
```

But I want to be able to find and remove a specific binded function from the array. When I check my array, it is all `[MyFunction(), MyFunction(), MyFunction()]`. So normal methods to find an element in array and delete it does not work with this array.

I tried removing duplicates using unique but it didn't work. When I try to find the index with

```
FunctionList.indexOf(MyFunction.bind(null, Argument, Argument2));
```

it gives me `-1`.

A specific function can be anywhere in the array so I can't use methods like deleting the last element.

Comment: You cannot find that. You need the actual reference to the function to find it in the array and since you don't store a reference anywhere, you can't differentiate between the functions.

Comment: You will not be able to do that. You may want to push an object having the parameters and the function into the array like this - `FunctionList.push({argList: [null, Argument, Argument2], func: MyFunction.bind(null, Argument, Argument2)});`

And then use the argList to find the index.

Answer (score 0):

`.bind` returns a new function object and two different functions objects will never be equal to each other.

If you want to remove a specific function you either have to keep a reference to it around, or you have to store the information differently. For example you could create a structure like the following to the array, instead of a bound function:

```
{
   func: MyFunction,
   args: [Argument1, Argument2],
}
```

Then in order to find an entry with the same function and arguments you can compare each entry manually using `findIndex`:

```
FunctionList.findIndex(entry => {
  return entry.func === MyFunction && [Argument1, Argument2].every((arg, i) => arg === entry.args[i]);
});
```

(of course you would package this nicely into a reusable function)

If you have to keep bound functions in the array then you could consider storing the original function and arguments in properties of the bound function and apply the above solution. E.g.

```
const newFunc = MyFunction.bind(null, Argument, Argument2);
newFunc.original = MyFunction;
newFunc.originalArgs = [Argument, Argument2];
FunctionList.push(newFunc);
```